# Instalar 2 versiones de PHP en XAMPP

Tags: php

Cómo puedo instalar dos versiones de `php` en `xampp`? 
Como verán **xampp** trae instalada la versión de **PHP 7.2** pero lamentablemente me esta trayendo complicaciones a la hora de crear documentos word con php, yo uso la librería **PHPWord** porque es la única que he encontrado gratuita hasta ahorita pero me he dado cuenta que esta librería no es compatible con la versión php 7 por lo que necesito instalar otra versión mas baja como por ejemplo **php 5.6**.

Quiero saber si pueden ayudarme con esto como instalar otra versión de php en xampp.

Comment: Simplemente descarga en instala ambas versiones, pero solo levanta los servicios de la version que necesites y detenlos cuando ya no, para que asi puedas usar la otra

Comment: Pero en una sola versión de xampp no se puede instalar 2 versiones de php?? Porque antes usaba wamp server y en una sola versión si se podia instalar dos versiones de php

Comment: Como comento @LeviArista deberias de instalarlo en diferentes carpetas, busca la version del php que contenga el xampp y los instalas, y solo levantas los servicios del php que quieras

Comment: No @JorgeAlonso, las instalaciones de xammp son independientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este link me fue útil para lo que necesitaba hacer: 
https://silas.com.ng/multiple-php-version-xampp-windows/

Answer (score 2):

Puedes descargar las versiones de `PHP` que necesites y colocarlas en sus propios directorios, por ejemplo

```
c:\php5\

c:\php7\
```

Todo lo que necesitas hacer es decirle a tu servidor web (`Apache`) qué versión de `PHP` usar, así este cargará el módulo apropiado. En `Apache` puede hacer esto buscando el archivo `httpd.conf` y luego editando la línea apropiada:

```
LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so
```

Tendrás que descubrir la ruta correcta, por supuesto, esto es solo un ejemplo.

Guarda el `httpd.conf` y reinicia su servidor. Ten en cuenta que si no lo reinicias, los cambios no tendrán efecto.

Es necesario editar el archivo `.conf` y luego reiniciar `Apache`. Hacer esto solo te lleva un par de segundos, puedes documentar cual estas usando también en el archivo.

```
Use PHP 5:

LoadModule php5_module c:\php5\libphp5.so
#LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so

Use PHP 7:

#LoadModule php5_module c:\php5\libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module c:\php7\libphp7.so
```

No necesita múltiples versiones de `XAMPP` , ni arranque dual, ni usar una máquina diferente, ni ninguna de las otras "soluciones" que han sugerido soluciones complicadas. Si quieres usar `XAMPP` solo dile qué versión de `PHP` usar. Esta es la forma más rápida y eficiente de hacerlo, y solo requiere una instalación `XAMPP`.